# N-th power of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find the formula for the n-th power of this matrix.

$$
\pmatrix{1&1\\1&0}
$$

Well $f^2 = \pmatrix{2&1\\1&1}$ and $f^3 = \pmatrix{3&2\\2&1}$ and $f^4 = \pmatrix{5&3\\3&2}$
and $f^5 = \pmatrix{8&5\\5&3}$...

I can't seem to find the pattern here. Would someone mind helping me

Comment: Do you mean the matrix $\pmatrix{1&1\\1&0}$?

Comment: Do you know the [Fibonacci sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence)?  Those numbers should look familiar

Comment: These are just the *Fibonacci* numbers.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom yes.

Comment: @RossMillikan I have never heard of those till today, how are you supposed to see that pattern without know about those?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** For $F = \pmatrix{1&1\\1&0}$, show (perhaps inductively) that
$$
F^n = F^{n-1} + F^{n-2}
$$
**Inductive step:**
$$
F^{n+1} = F \cdot F^n = F(F^{n-1} + F^{n-2}) = F^n + F^{n-1}
$$
For the base case, note that $F^0 = I$.